# RTL8168 network card doesn't work on Linux Mint 18

Tags: linux, ubuntu

My network card is there, and the wire connection is good. But I don't know why there is no working wired connection.

The following is some information you may need.

```
john@john-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M ~ $ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 06
       serial: 90:2b:34:45:1f:44
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:25 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f2104000-f2104fff memory:f2100000-f2103fff
```

The output of `ifconfig`:

```
john@john-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M ~ $ sudo ifconfig -a
enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:2b:34:45:1f:44                       
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1                          
          RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0                   
          TX packets:53 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0                  
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000                                            
          RX bytes:990 (990.0 B)  TX bytes:8473 (8.4 KB)                            

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback                                                   
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0                                          
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host                                                 
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1                                        
          RX packets:10871 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0                          
          TX packets:10871 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0                          
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1                                                           
          RX bytes:1111323 (1.1 MB)  TX bytes:1111323 (1.1 MB)
```

The output of `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
john@john-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M ~ $ sudo cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: So...what doesn't work? Which errors are your getting? What do you expect? How did you configured your network (card)?

Comment: I cannot get IP. cannot ping to the gateway. neither of DHCP and static IP works.

Comment: You have to show how you configured your network.

Comment: Load the driver `sudo modprobe r8168`

Comment: there is no r8168 but r8169 has been loaded already.

Comment: @gf_ I did nothing. It should work without any extra configuration.

Comment: Well, you showed your `/etc/network/interfaces`, but inside there only `lo` is defined. Up until now, you failed to show **how** you configured `enp3s0`. "It should work without any extra configuration": I'm not sure if this is a headless server (you posted first on SF), or a machine running a desktop environment, but in case it's the former, you're just plain wrong. Anyway, this discussion leads to next to nothing, so I'm out. Good luck and all the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a working internet connection , then compile the right driver `r8168`

Enable the *universe* repo by adding the following line to your `sources.list`:

```
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe
```

Update and install the `r8168-dkms` package :

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms
```

Reboot your system