# rtl8168 based NIC not detected on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, network-interface, realtek

As the NIC itself is currently not working, I have only limited information as I am not running the system right now. The issue I have is that after a kernel upgrade the NIC stopped working. I saw [the answer about re-installing the DKMS module](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317398/rtl8168-network-card-doesnt-work-on-linux-mint-18) but this did not work. I downloaded the package via packages.ubuntu.com, transferred it via a USB stick and installed it manually via dpkg. It installed without error-message but the NIC was still not detected, even after a full reboot.

Following the [official Realtek support page](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software) I can see that the module is only support for kernel up to 5.6:

[image: screenshot from realtek page]

I do have a newer kernel (5.8 I think). This might explain why the NIC stopped working after the kernel upgrade.

Any ideas how this can be fixed?

Comment: Not how it can be fixed, but a command to check if the driver is installed is `lspci -s PCIADDRESS -k`. You get the PCIADDRESS from the output of `lspci`. I would also look for kernel messages regarding the interface or the driver (`dmesg` command).

Comment: @D'ArcyNader how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer of @GAD3R pointed me to the solution. The package `linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04` went missing for some reason.

After either a `dist-upgrade` or `upgrade` command the mentioned package went missing. This package is an indirect dependency to the `linux-headers-generic` package. As this was unavailable the DKMS module was not built on kernel upgrade.

The solution was to download both the appropriate (kernel versoin can be found using `uname -r`) `.deb` files for the two above mentioned packages via https://packages.ubuntu.com and installing them manually.

Installing them (using `dpkg -i`) automatically triggered the build of the DKMS modules, and after a reboot the issue was fixed.

As a precaution I manually installed `linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04`. That way they should be marked as "manually installed" and should no longer disappear. Considering that the package name contains `20.4` I'm almost certain this won't survive the next `dist-upgrade`, and I did not see a corresponding meta-package.

So I'll likely come across this post again in the future. In which case: Hello, future-me :)

Comment: thanks, like this answer pointed out, all I need is reinstall r8168-dkms package. for some reason the module is not built  successfully during last massive package upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Manually install the driver from [this git repository](https://github.com/mtorromeo/r8168):

```
git clone https://github.com/mtorromeo/r8168.git
cd r8168
sudo ./autorun.sh
lsmod | grep r8168
```

Blacklist `r8169` driver:

```
echo "blacklist r8169" |sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```